# Should there be a trailing slash in the permalink

Tags: permalinks

Which WordPress permalink structure is better in terms of performance and SEO:

`/%post_id%/%postname%`

or

`/%post_id%/%postname%/`

Does it matter?

Google has big discussion [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html). But it's not from a WordPress perspective.

Which one should I use and why?

**Edit**: I noticed I get an advantage using `/%post_id%/%postname%` since any mistake etc after `sitename.com/123/wrong-words?some=params&etc=etc` gets redirected to the correct post. But for `sitename.com/123/correct-full-postname/someword` generates a [404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190744/why-wordpress-cant-handle-site-com-postname-someword-gives-404).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference performance-wise, if it did, there'd be something seriously wrong with WordPress.

The same goes for Google, if a lot of super smart people earning 100k salaries can't write software that handles a trailing slash, then something is terribly wrong with the world.

Either way, WordPress puts the `rel="canonical"` tag in the header so regardless of wether there's a trailing slash or not when you visit the page, Google will see that tag and see what the canonical authoritative URL for that page is.

As a side-note, Google doesn't reserve special rules for WordPress sites, they're all just sites as far as Google is concerned.

Comment: Why can't worpress handle `sitename.com/123/correct-full-postname/somewordbymistake` instead returns a 404?

Comment: That's an entirely different question that's unrelated to this one concerning rewrite rules and permalinks. Feel free to ask a new question, but I'd rather not introduce scope creep into this question ( though I agree it's relevant to your situation, just not your question )

Comment: Please do have a look http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190744/why-wordpress-cant-handle-site-com-postname-someword-gives-404

Comment: Given it an upvote!